# Find the almost sure limit of $X_n/n$, where each random variable $X_n$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $n$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

> $X_{n}$ independent and $X_n \sim \mathcal{P}(n) $  meaning that $X_{n}$ has Poisson distributions with parameter $n$. What is the $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{X_{n}}{n}$ almost surely ?

I think we can write $X(n) \sim X(1)+X(1)+\cdots+X(1)$ where the sum is taken on independent identical distribution then use the law of large number. But I am not sure that is it correct or not. Can anyone give me some hints? Thank you in advance!

Comment: No you cannot write that, first because no kind of relationship between the random variables $X(\lambda)$ for diferent values of $\lambda$ is postulated, second because $X(1)+X(1)+\cdots+X(1)$ is not Poisson. All this means you need to use more robust tools... such as the first Borel-Cantelli lemma. Any idea to pursue?

Comment: @i707107 Actually, no. Sorry.

Comment: @Did I believe the question actually being asked is: 

"Let $X_n\sim\mathsf{Pois}(n)$, $n=1,2,\ldots$. Does $\frac{X_n}n$ converge almost surely? If so, what is the limit?"

But I am still puzzled as to what $X(\lambda)$ could actually mean.

Comment: Hi @Math1000 You are right. I will rephrase the question.

Comment: @Math1000 Yes this is the question. (And I think we can overcome the oddity of the notation $X(\lambda)$ vs $X_\lambda$, if this is the point of your comment.)

Comment: Yes, because $X$ is a function, and the notation $X(\cdot)$ suggests the evaluation of $X$ at a point.

Comment: Wait, did I mention central limit theorem? I thought not...

Comment: @Did What should I do? I am not sure now.

Comment: @ThomasEdison First check the exact statement of the exercise. Second explain how you came to the idea that the LLN was even relevant. (The LLN might apply, but in a very specific situation, which is not when $(X_n)$ is independent.)

Comment: @ThomasEdison "It seemed in the comments to OP's question that nobody was listening to me." Funny, this is exactly the impression I got about the way **you** "listen" to **my** comments...

Comment: @i707107 You are misleading the OP, big time.

Comment: @Did Okay, I will try to listen to you. What is wrong with this statement? 'A Poisson random variable with parameter $n\in \mathbb{N}$ being equal to an independent sum of $n$ identical Poisson random variable with parameter $1$?'

Comment: @i707107 Nothing. And this is not the statement you would need to make your idea work.

Comment: @i707107 Nope, it does not. Let me note that you suddenly stopped to write down the details of the argument you have in mind. Which is a shame because if you did, you would see that no LLN applies here (except in a very specific situation which is most probably not the one the OP or you have in mind).

Comment: @Did I would like to see your answer too. Then you would use Chernoff bound for Poisson distribution, right?

Comment: @i707107 Indeed, any large deviations bound (say, Chernoff) leads directly to the conclusion.

Comment: @ThomasEdison Please see Did's comments and my comments on the answer by Math1000.

Comment: @i707107 I saw your comments. Thank you so much for honesty !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X_n\sim\mathsf{Pois}(n)$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$, then $n^{-1}X_n\stackrel{\mathrm{a.s.}}\longrightarrow 1$. It suffices to show that for all $\varepsilon>0$, 
$$\mathbb P\left(\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left|n^{-1}X_n-1\right|<\varepsilon\right)=1. $$

We have $$\left\{\left|n^{-1}X_n-1\right|<\varepsilon\right\}^c = \left\{X_n\leqslant n(1-\varepsilon) \right\}\cup\left\{X_n\geqslant n(1+\varepsilon) \right\}, $$
so the Chernoff bounds yield $$\mathbb P(X_n\leqslant n(1-\varepsilon)) \leqslant \frac{e^{-n}(ne)^{n(1-\varepsilon)}}{(n(1-\varepsilon))^{n(1-\varepsilon)}}=  \left(e^{\varepsilon}(1-\varepsilon)^{1-\varepsilon} \right)^{-n} $$
and
$$\mathbb P(X_n\geqslant n(1+\varepsilon)) \leqslant \frac{e^{-n}(ne)^{n(1+\varepsilon)}}{(n(1+\varepsilon))^{n(1+\varepsilon)}}=
\left(e^{-\varepsilon}(1+\varepsilon)^{1+\varepsilon} \right)^{-n} . $$

Now

$$e^\varepsilon(1-\varepsilon)^{1-\varepsilon} = e^{\varepsilon + (1-\varepsilon)\log(1-\varepsilon)}=e^{\frac{\varepsilon^2}2+O(\varepsilon^3)}>1 $$
and 
$$e^{-\varepsilon}(1+\varepsilon)^{1+\varepsilon} = e^{-\varepsilon+(1+\varepsilon)\log(1+\varepsilon)}=e^{\frac{\varepsilon^2}2+O(\varepsilon^3)}>1, $$
so $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X_n\leqslant n(1-\varepsilon))\leqslant\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(e^{\varepsilon}(1-\varepsilon)^{1-\varepsilon} \right)^{-n}<\infty $$ and 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X_n\geqslant n(1+\varepsilon))\leqslant\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(e^{-\varepsilon}(1+\varepsilon)^{1+\varepsilon} \right)^{-n}<\infty.$$
It follows from the first Borel-Cantelli lemma that $$\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} \{X_n\leqslant n(1-\varepsilon)\}\right)=\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} \{X_n\geqslant n(1+\varepsilon)\}\right)=0,$$
and so we conclude.

Comment: This proves that $Y_n/n\to1$ almost surely, for some sequence $(Y_n)$ such that, for each $n$, $Y_n$ and $X_n$ have the same distribution. Nothing can be deduced from this about the almost sure convergence of $X_n/n$...

Comment: @Did it is better to write your solution too.

Comment: @Did Ah, I see now. Allow me to revise the answer.

Comment: @Did Then can we not say that if $X_n \sim B(n,p)$, then $X_n/n \rightarrow p$ a.s? because $X_n$ and $Y_n= B_1+\cdots +B_n$ are the same distribution where $B_i$'s are iid Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p$, so it just says that $Y_n/n \rightarrow p$ a.s, but not for $X_n/n$?

Comment: @i707107 It happens that $U_n/n\to p$ almost surely, for every random sequence $(U_n)$ such that each $U_n$ is binomial $(n,p)$, *but this is not for the reason you say*.

Comment: @Did I am still not sure why my argument cannot apply. It seems that it works for binomial distribution as you say, but why not for Poisson?

Comment: @i707107 The result holds for Poisson and binomial. But the argument to prove it that you explain, based on the LLN, fails for Poisson and binomial.

Comment: @Did Can you please explain why it fails? It seems that you don't use LLN to prove that if $X_n\sim B(n,p)$ then $X_n/n\rightarrow p$ a.s.  I see that large deviation bound can prove these results, but still don't see why specifically LLN does not apply.

Comment: @i707107 Again: please explain specifically the sequence you want to apply the LLN to (which random variables, which independences), otherwise I fail to see what we are discussing.

Comment: @Did I see your point now. You are concerned about how random variables are made of. So, just by assuming $X_n\sim \textrm{Poisson}(n)$ would not imply that $X_n = Y_1+\cdots + Y_n$ with iid random variables $Y_i \sim \textrm{Poisson}(1)$. Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: My argument would apply if it is assumed that $X_t$ is a Poisson process. That's what I had understood OP's question in the first place, but looking back OP's problem again, it is not assumed to be Poisson process. It is my misunderstanding, and possibly mislead OP. I will delete all of my comments based on this misunderstanding.

Comment: @Did Would there be any example that $X_n\sim Y_n$  with $Y_n\rightarrow a \ \textrm{a.s.}$ and $X_n\not\rightarrow a \ \textrm{a.s.}$?

Comment: @i707107 Consider $X_n=\mathbf 1_{nU<1}$, where $U$ is uniform on $(0,1)$, and $(Y_n)$ independent with $P(Y_n=1)=\frac1n=1-P(X_n=0)$. Then $P(X_n\to0)=1$ but $\sum\frac1n$ diverges hence $Y_n=1$ for infinitely many $n$, almost surely, by Borel-Cantelli second lemma, in particular, $P(Y_n\to0)=0$.

Comment: @i707107 Indeed, your argument show that if $(X_t)$ is a Poisson **process** with intensity $1$ then $X_n/n\to1$ almost surely, by the LLN.

Comment: @Did Thank you for the clarification, and I am very sorry for all of cynically sounding comments that I had previously. Great to know that I still have much to learn.

Comment: @Did I think that $Y_n$ with indicator on $(h_n, h_n+\frac1n) \ \mathrm{mod} \ 1$ would also work, where $h_n= 1 + 1/2 + \cdots + 1/n$.

Comment: @Math1000 The new proof is complete, provided one shows that $$e^{\varepsilon}(1-\varepsilon)^{1-\varepsilon}>1,\qquad e^{-\varepsilon}(1+\varepsilon)^{1+\varepsilon}>1.$$

Comment: Correction: the new proof is incomplete, since the step "It follows that $\mathbb P\left(\left|k^{-1}X_k-1\right|<\varepsilon \right)=1$" does not hold. The preceding construction only shows that $\mathbb P\left(\left|k^{-1}X_k-1\right|<\varepsilon \right)>1-\varepsilon$, which does not allow to conclude. Please modify this step and the computations which prepare it, using Borel-Cantelli lemma (as mentioned in the very first comment to the OP...).

Comment: @Did For the first point, $e^{\varepsilon}(1-\varepsilon)^{1-\varepsilon}=e^{\varepsilon^2/2+O(\varepsilon^3)},\qquad e^{-\varepsilon}(1+\varepsilon)^{1+\varepsilon}=e^{\varepsilon^2/2+O(\varepsilon^3)}.$

Comment: @Did For the second point, by the above, we have $\sum_n P(X_n\leqslant n(1-\varepsilon)) <\infty$ and $\sum_n P(X_n\geqslant n(1+\varepsilon)) <\infty$. Then by first Borel-Cantelli lemma, we have the result.

Comment: @i707107 I know, thanks. Please address your computations to the OP... :-)

Comment: @Did I knew that you would know, just wanted to make sure what I have is correct. I think the OP will get a notification by my comments anyways.